# Converting a string to all CAPS and returning it from a function

Tags: arrays, c, string, char, cs50

```
const char* CAPITALIZE(string val)
{
    char valCap[strlen(val)];
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(val); i++)
    {
        char n = val[i];
        if (n >= 'a' && n <= 'z')
        {
            n -= 32;
            valCap[i] = n;
        }
        else
        {
            valCap[i] = n;
        }
    }
    valCap[strlen(val) + 1] = '\0';
    return valCap;
}
```

What this is supposed to do is:

1. Take in a string.
2. Capitalize all letters in it.
3. Return the string.

But it's not working. I tried finding a solution, but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: This won't work because a) `char valCap[strlen(val)];` does not allow for string terminator, and b) it won't exist after return from function.

Comment: string = const char*?

Comment: Options are a) allocate dynamic memory for a new string, b) pass a buffer for the new string as another argument, c) uppercase the string in-place.

Comment: ...and even if you had the extra byte for terminator, `valCap[strlen(val) + 1] = '\0';` is still wrong (1 too far).

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you! I will research the instructions you provided.

Comment: I find it helful to consider very short strings to visualise these things, say length 0 or 1.

Comment: @Mhf A Clone of google.com without flexbox or grid: (I completed it you can have a look there) https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/MWjqmmq

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal Hi! Thanks! I deleted it because it got downvotes. I will put the question back up again? Because it may help others? Thanks a lot for this!

Comment: You're welcome @Mhf ✌

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`valCap` is a local variable, its lifetime will end when the function returns, accessing a function's local variable after it has returned amounts to [undefined behavior](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3).

There are several ways you can fix this:

1. For the variable to be safely returned, you'd need to extend its lifetime either by declaring a pointer and allocate memory for it:

   ```
   #include <stdlib.h>

   //...

   char *valCap = malloc(strlen(val) + 1); //note the + 1 for the null character
   ```

   Later you would need to free it when it's no longer used.

- Or by making it static:

  ```
  static char valCap[strlen(val) + 1]; //note the + 1 for the null character
  ```

  This extends the lifetime of the variable, it will live as long as the program itself.

2. Alternatively, you could pass a second argument containing the destination string, instead of declaring it in the function.

- In all the above cases you'll need to properly null terminate the string:

  ```
   valCap[strlen(val)] = '\0';
  ```

3. The simpler way, the one I would use, would be to capitalize the string passed as an argument.

   ```
   #include <ctype.h>

   //...

   void CAPITALIZE(string val)
   {  
       for (int i = 0; i < strlen(val); i++)
       {
           val[i] = toupper(val[i]);
       }
   }
   ```

- Or, since the argument is really a pointer to the string <sup>1</sup>:

  ```
  void CAPITALIZE(string val)
  {  
      while(*val != 0) //or '\0'
      {
          *val = toupper(*val);
          val++;
      }
  }
  ```

  If you want to keep the original string unaltered or if the original string is constant, you can pass a copy instead.

You can keep your original capitalization strategy and apply one of these fixes, but using `toupper` is  safer, more portable, and simpler.

<sup>1. **cs50** `string` is nothing more than a `typedef` of `char*`.</sup>

Comment: I really appreciate your extended support. I am going to analyze each of the methods provided to understand further.

Comment: Beware of in-place modifications of strings.  `CAPITALIZE( "this is a string constant" );` will cause your program to fail if string constants are read-only.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Noted. Thanks!